# Lumpy oranges and pruning

Tags: fruit-trees, pruning

Why are my oranges lumpy and they only grow in the top of the tree out of reach? 
Can I trim to a more manageable height?

Comment: We've got a orchardist on board...I think it might be Giacomo.  We'll try to alert him for you.